# Symfony2 : Best way to check form, client side

Tags: validation, symfony, input, twig, client-side

I'm developing a form with Symfony2 : several text inputs and **one file input** (for one picture). I have defined some asserts (maxLength, minLength...) in my entity in order to check the form (isValid).

My problem is : if the user puts **bad data** in text input (text too long or too short...), **he still can submit the form**, and error and printed but the **user have to re-choose his picture**.

As I think it's impossible to keep the picture in the form after bad validation, I should maybe check the form in client side (javascript), before submit.

So, is there an automatic way to do this (to forbidden submit until data are correct)? Can we get the assert minLength, maxLength value in twig ?

Thank you !
Ben.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use js validation before submitting the data, using some js form validation [tools](https://www.codefellows.org/blog/the-ten-best-javascript-libraries-for-form-validation-and-formatting), but this way you need the replicate the validation logic from the server, so if validation rules changes, you need to modify on both server and client side. I recommend this method to reduce the traffic between client-server.

If you don't want this, use ajax form submitting ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29541628/how-to-submit-form-ajax-in-symfony2)). You still validate the form using symfony, but the page won't refresh, so you won't lose the attached file. But this generates additional traffic to server, and you also need to implement error displaying using javascript.

Comment: Ajax, I didn't think to ajax. Thank you :)